0 libraries and 1 linked data-blocks are missing

The warning appears when opening my rig file, or opening a file where the rig is linked.
In the rig itseslf there's no orphaned data, or driver errors, or missing files.
So i cannot figure out what it is that is missing.
also info and outliner editors have no extra details.
I am not at liberty to share the rig, so my question is how you would find these issues, the same way missing libraries get highlighted in the outliner.
